# How can I allow the touchpad to keep working while a keyboard button is pressed?

Tags: touchpad

I'm using Wayland in Ubuntu 22.04.

When any keyboard key is pressed, my trackpad is completely disabled. I would like to disable this feature.

I found the following using the `libinput` command:
<sub>*(The output heavily truncated to only include the TouchPad device)*</sub>

```
$ sudo libinput list-devices
[...]
Device:           SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event7
Group:            9
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             70x50mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
[...]
```

There seems to be an enabled property called `Disable-w-typing`, which I assume is the culprit for disabling my trackpad.

How can turn off this `Disable-w-typing` property and keep my trackpad functioning all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable `disable-w-typing` using the `gsettings` command.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing false
```

You can enable it back with the following command.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing true
```

Comment: also available in "setting"/"tweaks" under "keyboard and mouse"

Comment: Ah, nice. I looked in the normal "settings" and didn't find it there. Forgot to look in "Tweaks" though. @Rinzwind You can add that as an answer as well.

Comment: nah your q and a :+